# "ours being the last country” vs “ours is the last country”

Tags: tense, gerund-clauses

> Several countries have attempted to do this, **ours being the last one**.

This is not a participial clause as there are two different subjects.

What if I put **is** instead?

Comment: I would word the sentence as 'Several countries have attempted to do this, ours (or our country) is the most recent to do so.' Your country is the last one only if no other county ever attempt to do this in the future.

Comment: @MarkRipley I wonder if you could please tell me the grammar of being in this context. My sentence is just an example.

Comment: It was "was" vs "being" before. Edited

Comment: I don't know the name of this grammatical device, but it seems to have the same structure as, e.g., "We walked through the woods at night, the stars shining brightly in the sky." The phrasing makes it clear that there is a connection between the two - in this case, that the event in the second clause is occurring at the same time and place as the first. Note that the comma is correct, but if you rephrased it as two independent clauses, you not only lose the sense of connection, but you need to separate them with a semicolon or period.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that "is" and "was" are different tenses of the verb "*to be*".

So, you are quite correct that your sentence could *mean* the same if you said:

> Several countries have attempted to do this, ours **was** the last one.

The expression you are asking about which uses the present tense "being" is quite common and idiomatic. Because you are speaking about a number of countries that have attempted something, and you are identifying your country from that collection, it is quite correct to use the present tense. If that seems odd, imagine that all these countries that have made past attempts are presented to you in a list, and you are asked to identify your country from that list. You would say "that one *is* my country", not "that one *was* my country" - because it is *still your country*.

So, saying:

> Several countries have attempted to do this, ours being the last one.

Your country *is* the last on a  list of countries that attempted whatever it is they attempted.

Comment: Can I add "with" and say: "... with ours being the last one."

Comment: @user100323 - yes you can say that.

Answer (score 1):

This is not so much a matter of grammar as it is one of punctuation. As *written*, **being** may not be replaced with **is**. If it were, the complete sentence would contain two improperly joined independent clauses.

Let's review the rules of *written* English:

With very few exceptions, a finite clause contains a verb that that is tensed (it indicates past or present) and conjugated (it indicates person and number). The clause **Several countries have attempted to do this** is recognizably finite because the auxiliary verb **have** indicates the present tense and is conjugated for a subject that is not 3rd-person singular. The clause **ours is the last one** is also recognizably finite because the verb **is** indicates the present tense and is conjugated for the 3rd-person singular.

Here's the key rule: multiple finite clauses may exist in the same sentence only if one of these conditions is met:

1. the clauses are joined by a coordinating conjunction, most commonly *and, but,* or *or;*
2. the clauses are joined by a subordinating conjunction like *because* or *although*;
3. or the clauses are separated by a colon or semicolon.

The proposed sentence

> Several countries have attempted to do this, ours is the last one.

does not meet any of these conditions, as both clauses are finite but there are no conjunctions, a colon, or a semicolon. Most copyeditors would reject such a sentence.

Two clauses may exist in a single sentence without meeting these conditions if only one of them is finite. That is the case with the original sentence:

> Several countries have attempted to do this, *ours being the last one.*

The second clause, which I have italicized, is not finite: **being** shows neither tense nor person nor number. Rather, the clause is an example of what traditional grammar calls an absolute phrase, a type of *non*-finite clause. Martha Kolln (*Understanding English Grammar*) explains the structure this way:

> **The absolute phrase** (also known as the *nominative absolute*) is a structure independent from the main sentence; in form the absolute phrase is
> a noun phrase that includes a postnoun modifier. The modifier is commonly an *-en* or *-ing* participle or participial phrase . . . The absolute
> phrase introduces an idea related to the sentence as a whole, not to any
> one of its parts:
>
> *Our car having developed engine trouble*, we stopped for the night
> at a roadside rest area.
>
> *The weather being warm and clear*, we decided to have a picnic.

The meaning of the sentence is exactly this, as OP has guessed:

> Several countries have attempted to do this. Ours is the last one.

The primary difference (for this discussion) is that the absolute construction permits both clauses to exist in the same sentence without a conjunction or any special punctuation.